# Rest authentication with spring security and mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

I've implemented a `Spring` app with `mongodb` and now I've implemented [Rest authentication with Spring security and Mongodb](https://www.codementor.io/gtommee97/rest-authentication-with-spring-security-and-mongodb-j8wgh8kg7), and now I have to add the `Authorization` header, and it only shows the data from the api call if the `Authorization` is ok, from now it's ok, but I'm wondering how do I get this value? I mean I want to make a Login to the app, should I have an authorization for this? If not, the login response should return this authorization to use it in next calls?
I also have read about `aws token` also of `oauth2`, but I really want to know the process, I mean, what's the flow a normal user can Log in to the app and then make calls with authorizations?

My platforms are :

DB -- MongoDB

Server -- Spring

Web -- Angular

App -- Android

This is a project for a Quiz game, that could support multigame options (more than 1 player playing at once)

So what I need to understand is from APP / WEB I have to make a call let's say api/v1/login and then send the user and password, ok, where's the part when I have to create the bcrypted and salt stuff to store it into db? Do I have to do it on the app and then send for instance the SHA stuff via JSON in the Login call or it's better to send the password to server so server does all of the stuff and store the stuff on the db?

Answer (score 3):

In the scenario you describe there is no sense to use neither *OpenID Connect* or *OAuth2*. There is a single server for both authentication and resources. The scenario could be roughly this:

1. Client (Angular or App) send the credentials to the server in plain text over a secured HTTP connection to log in
2. Server responds with an *access* and *refresh token*
3. Both tokens need to be saved on the client device (e.g. Local Storage)
4. You send the *access token* along with every request that requires authentication
5. Before the *access token* expires you trigger a certain REST call to refresh the tokens using your *refresh token*
6. Server sends back a new *access* and a new *refresh token*. Store them and delete the old ones.

Using *SpringBoot* you pretty much get it all for free. Unless you don't a have specific example I'd spare giving code snippets. You'll find wonderful and concise examples on the [auth0 site](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/).

Find [here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/23/angular-6-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial) an Angular tutorial of how to send the access token along with your requests

Regarding your DB questions, a simple but valid scenario could be to store (in the DB) the **encrypted** password alongside your user. If a user logs in, he will send you the plain text password which you need to encrypt and compare it to the one you stored. Never store the plain text password, just use it for the login process. There are several [best practices](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/05/best-practices-while-dealing-with.html) you might want to consider using passwords in Java applications.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, but Matt could you please especify what should I do on DB? So, should I save the Bcrypted password? and it's a good idea to check if user == user and password == password instead of user == user and passwordencrypted == passwordencrypted?

Comment: I've added a section in the post regarding the login process.

Comment: Thanks Matt, nice answers, there is I guess the last question I have, how do apps/web knows that token has expired? when I do an api call it returns 403 for instance and then I have to do the extra call?

Comment: Speaking of tokens you typically (but not necessarily) mean a JWT which is a JSON structure that can contain multiple properties, among many others also the time when the token was issued and when it will expire. With this information you know when to refresh the token. There is no need to have the backend check the validity of the token. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to you to use Spring Security, OAuth2 and JWT tokens in order to protect your REST API.
The flow is the following:

- user can log on the app
- a token is generated
- this token is set in the header of each request

Usually tokens have a time duration
Basically OAuth2 defines 2 entities:

- Authorization Server: it's the entity responsible for the authorization process. It checks the provided credentials and if all is OK it generates the token
- Resource Server: it's the entity who will expose the REST API. This
  entity will check if in every request a token is present and the
  token is valid

Moe information are available here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

**UPDATE**

Here https://github.com/angeloimm/spring_oauth I uploaded a simple sample og Spring (and not spring boot) OAuth JWT authentication based on DB H2.

You can download it and adapt it to mongodb. I think it's enough simple to adapt it. Sadly it's a very intense working period for me and I'm not able in doing it.

I hope it's useful

Angelo

Comment: Oauth is an authorization delegation protocol, not an authentication one. Oauth2 along with a JWT authentication layer is known as Open Id Connect (OIDC)

Comment: So, I have to store them in the cache of the app and in the cache of the web? I mean the access_token and the refresh_token? how do I get them from both sides?

Comment: Who can generate the access_token and the refresh_token is the Authorization Server. Once you get them you must store them. How store them depends on your business logic. E.g. if the access_token never expires, well you should persist it in some way. Otherwise you can have a cache with duration equals to the token duration

Comment: Could you please provide an example? You get those from the Spring? so I have to send them as an answer to Login? I don't need examples about Web or Android, I need examples to how to provide them by Server and what to store there

Comment: Sorry I have been busy. Tomorrow I’ll provide a full working example

Comment: @AngeloImmediata could you add the example please?

Comment: See my edit section. If OK can you accept this as exact answer?

Comment: Angelo but how do I adapt your code  to spring boot? I need to use springboot

Comment: I don't want to use a webapp from spring I want to use for example angular

Comment: The baeldung link is for spring boot. I think you have all to adapt